# Let $f(x)\in K[x]$ ($K$ field). Prove that if $(f(x),f´(x))=1$ (greatest common divisor is 1) then $f(x)$ does not have multiple roots in $K$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, divisibility, roots

Please I would like you to tell me if my proof is correct

Let $f(x)\in K[x]$ ($K$ field). Prove that if $(f(x),f´(x))=1$ (greates common divisor is 1) then $f(x)$ does not have multiple roots in $K$

my attempt:
Suppose that $f(x)$ has multiple roots in $K$. Let $a$ be one of those roots with multiplicity $m$ then $f(x)=(x-a)^{m}g(x)$ for some $g(x)\in K[x]$.

If $a$ is a root of $f(x)$ with multiplicity $m$ then $a$ is a root of $f´(x)$ with multiplicity $m-1$ hence $f´(x)=(x-a)^{m-1}h(x)$ for some $h(x)\in K[x]$

$$f(x)=(x-a)^{m}g(x)=(x-a)^{m-1}(x-a)g(x)=(x-a)^{m-1}q(x)$$ ($q(x)=(x-a)g(x)$) therefore

$(x-a)^{m-1}|f(x)$ ($(x-a)^{m-1}$ divides $f(x)$) and

$(x-a)^{m-1}|f´(x)$  ($(x-a)^{m-1}$ divides $f´(x)$)

but this is a contradiction because $(f(x),f´(x))=1$

therefore $f(x)$ does not have multiple roots in $K$

I really would appreciate your help :)

Comment: It's lookin' good!

Comment: Looks fine.  However the crucial point is that $m\ge2$: I think you should clearly state this and not leave it to the reader's imagination.

Comment: Right, you want to prove the contrapositive: If $f(x)$ has a multiple root, then $f'(x)$ and $f(x)$ have a common factor. You seem to have gotten it.

Comment: thanks a lot!!! and you are right david I need to clarify it :D

Comment: Only to mention that the if the characteristic of $K$ is positive and divides $m$, then the multiplicity of $a$ as a root of $f'$ will be greater than $m-1$. For instance, for $f = x^p \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$, where $p$ is a prime number, one has $f' = 0$.